# Starting multi instance apache on same server Permission Denied

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a few instances of apache that successfully run on my server and I added one more by copying the root directory and all its files.  I modified the conf/httpd.conf file to have `Listen 19080` but when I run the below startup command I get the below error. The instances are owned by someone else, so I'm unsure what startup command they use, but the below seems proper.  I'm running apache2

```
httpd -f conf/httpd.conf -k start

(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Comment: It's still trying to bind port 80, check configuration of your sites there could be port at `<VirtualHost>` or another `Listen` directive.

Comment: Do you have any `<VirtualHost>` directives that specify (or don't specify) a port? I believe those cause implicit Listen directives.